# How to implement NodeMouseOut event analog for TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, mouseout

I want to show a special pop-up control when user mouse `hovers` the node and hide it when mouse leaves the node.

We have `NodeMouseHover` event for first part, but what to do with hiding procedure?

Comment: You need a timer.  Check to see if you are over the control, and if so, which node.

Comment: Thank you. Even since this is workaround - it still will work, so make it as answer. I will accept it if no better answer will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timer could be used to test the mouse position:

```
public class TreeViewEx : TreeView {
  public event TreeViewEventHandler NodeMouseLeave;

  private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
  private TreeNode mouseNode = null;

  public TreeViewEx() {
    if (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Runtime) {
      timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
      timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
      timer.Enabled = true;
    }
  }

  protected void OnNoseMouseLeave(TreeViewEventArgs e) {
    if (this.NodeMouseLeave != null) {
      this.NodeMouseLeave(this, e);
    }
  }

  void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.PointToClient(MousePosition))) {
      TreeNode testNode = this.GetNodeAt(this.PointToClient(MousePosition));

      if (testNode == null) {
        if (mouseNode != null) {
          OnNoseMouseLeave(new TreeViewEventArgs(mouseNode));
          mouseNode = null;
        }
      } else {
        if (mouseNode != null && !testNode.Equals(mouseNode)) {
          OnNoseMouseLeave(new TreeViewEventArgs(mouseNode));
        }
        mouseNode = testNode;
      }
    } else {
      if (mouseNode != null) {
        OnNoseMouseLeave(new TreeViewEventArgs(mouseNode));
        mouseNode = null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```